# 'sudo' not recognized as an internal or external command. Trying to run sudo raspi-config

Tags: pi-3, rfid, sudo

I am building my first project on a Raspberry Pi 3 using an RFID HAT for Raspberry Pi. I am using Windows 10 IOT Core. The manual for the RFID HAT begins with this:

I2C/Serial interface is disabled by default in Raspberry Pi, To enable it type below command.

sudo raspi-config

I get the response: 'sudo' is not recognized...

Loads of other 'sudo' commands follow. I have done some hunting on this. One post suggests using 'runat' - also not recognized. another suggests using 'elevate' - also not recognized.

Comment: I bet the whole manual is written with Linux in mind: it's not just about `sudo`. You won't get `raspi-config` on Windows either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget Windows. It is NOT Linux. Use Raspberry Pi OS.

AFAIK Windows IOT is not currently supported.

Comment: That works @Milliways. Now I am just going to have to rewrite the other half of the project in Python (storing the results using a Web Service). (Previously written in C#)